# Loading libraries for use in an specific environment in R

Tags: r, environment

I have written some functions to facilitate repeated tasks among my R projects. I am trying to use an environment to load them easily but also prevent them from appearing when I use `ls()` or delete them with `rm(list=ls())`.

As a dummy example I have an environment loader function in a file that I can just source from my current project and an additional file for each specialized environment I want to have.

```bash
currentProject.R
environments/env_loader.R
environments/colors_env.R
```

env_loader.R

```
.environmentLoader <- function(env_file, env_name='my_env') {
    sys.source(env_file, envir=attach(NULL, name=env_name))
}

path <- dirname(sys.frame(1)$ofile) # this script's path

#
# Automatically load
.environmentLoader(paste(path, 'colors_env.R', sep='/'), env_name='my_colors')
```

colors_env.R

```
library(RColorBrewer) # this doesn't work

# Return a list of colors
dummyColors <- function(n) {
    require(RColorBrewer) # This doesn't work
    return(brewer.pal(n, 'Blues'))
}
```

CurrentProject.R

```
source('./environments/env_loader.R')

# Get a list of 5 colors
dummyColors(5)
```

This works great except when my functions require me to load a library. In my example, I need to load the `RColorBrewer` library to use the `brewer.pal` function in `colors_env.R`, but the way is now I just get an error `Error in brewer.pal(n, "Blues") : could not find function "brewer.pal"`.

I tried just using `library(RColorBrewer)` or using `require` inside my `dummyColors` function or adding stuff like `evalq(library("RColorBrewer"), envir=parent.env(environment()))` to the `colors_env.R` file but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using similar functions across projects, I would recommend creating an R package. It's essentially what you're doing in many ways, but you don't have reinvent a lot of the loading mechanisms, etc. Hadley Wickham's book [R Packages](https://r-pkgs.org/) is very good for this topic. It doesn't need to be a completely fully built out, CRAN ready sort of thing. You can just create a personal package with misc. functions you frequently use.

That being said, the solution for your specific question would be to explicitly use the namespace to call the function.

```
dummyColors <- function(n) {
    require(RColorBrewer) # This doesn't work
    return(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, 'Blues'))
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I haven't try making a package because I edit/add functions often. Anyways your solutions works but isn't there a way to make available the package functions the way library(RColorBrewer) would do it? The problem with your approach is that if I have to make many function calls it is kind of a pain to add the namespace everytime.

Comment: There is a way, I'm sure but I don't it seems overly complicated. When you build a package, there is already a simple mechanism to do just that. Maybe if you were trying to release to a public repo such as CRAN, it might matter, but if the package is for you, it doesn't matter if you edit it often. Instead of sourcing you just rebuild.  Check this [article out from Hilary Parker](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) about building minimal package for personal functions. A little old but the process is pretty much unchanged

Answer (score 1):

Create a package and then run it. Use kitten to build the boilerplate, copy your file to it, optionally build it if you want a .tar.gz file or omit that step if you don't need it and finally install it.  Then test it out.  We have assumed colors_env.R, shown in the question, is in current directory.

(Note that `require` should always be within an `if` so that if it does not load then the error is caught.  If not within an `if` use `library` which will guarantee an error message in that case.)

```
# create package
library(devtools)
library(pkgKitten)

kitten("colors")
file.copy("colors_env.R", "./colors/R")
build("colors") # optional = will create colors_1.0.tar.gz
install("colors")

# test
library(colors)
dummyColors(5)
## Loading required package: RColorBrewer
## [1] "#EFF3FF" "#BDD7E7" "#6BAED6" "#3182BD" "#08519C"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a lightweight alternative to packages, you could use [‘box’](https://klmr.me/box/) to use modules. In fact, what you are attempting to do is *exactly* solved by [‘box’ modules](https://klmr.me/box/articles/box.html).

The module system implemented by ‘box’ is reminiscent of other module systems in modern languages, such as JavaScript/TypeScript, Rust, Python, etc.

As an example, here’s a direct port of your code:

###### `environments/colors.r`

```r
# Use `box::use()` instead of `library()`:
box::use(RColorBrewer[...])

# Return a list of colors
#' @export
dummyColors <- function(n) {
    # Alternatively, you could also use `box::use()` locally:
    # box::use(RColorBrewer)
    return(brewer.pal(n, 'Blues'))
}
```

###### `CurrentProject.R`

```r
# By default, no exported names are attached when modules are imported
box::use(./environments/colors)

# Get a list of 5 colors
colors$dummyColors(5)

### Or, alternatively: ###

# `[...]` attaches all exported names:
box::use(./environment/colors[...])

dummyColors(5)
```